# Extract estimates of GAM

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am fairly new to R and presently reading a book “Generalized Additive Models”, an Introduction with R by Wood (2006) and going through some of the exercises, particularly the part on air pollution and death which is my area of interest. Using the mgcv package I run the following model.

```
library(gamair) 
library(mgcv) 
data(chicago) 

ap1<-gam(death ~ pm10median + so2median + o3median +s(time,bs="cr",k=200)+ s(tmpd,bs="cr"), data=chicago,family=poisson)
```

How can I extract the effect estimates of pm10median and 95% CI of x and export the output to CSV or any other option?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Save the summary of the model

```
summary_model <- summary(ap1)
```

The part you want (for the linear terms) is in the  `p.table` element

```
summary_model$p.table
                Estimate   Std. Error      z value    Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 4.7457425965 1.480523e-03 3205.4510971 0.000000000
pm10median  0.0002551498 9.384003e-05    2.7189871 0.006548217
so2median   0.0008898646 5.543272e-04    1.6053056 0.108426561
o3median    0.0002212612 2.248015e-04    0.9842516 0.324991826


write.csv(summary_model$p.table, file = 'p_table.csv')
```

If you want the spline terms, then this is

```
summary_model$s.table
               edf     Ref.df    Chi.sq       p-value
s(time) 167.327973 187.143378 1788.8201 4.948832e-259
s(tmpd)   8.337121   8.875807  110.5231  1.412415e-19
```

You can calculate the 95% CI by hand and add these If you wish. (Will use Z score due to high DF)

```
p_table <- data.frame(summary_model$p.table)
p_table <- within(p_table, {lci <- Estimate - qnorm(0.975) * Std..Error
                            uci <- Estimate + qnorm(0.975) * Std..Error})
p_table
               Estimate   Std..Error      z.value    Pr...z..          uci           lci
(Intercept) 4.7457425965 1.480523e-03 3205.4510971 0.000000000 4.7486443674  4.742841e+00
pm10median  0.0002551498 9.384003e-05    2.7189871 0.006548217 0.0004390729  7.122675e-05
so2median   0.0008898646 5.543272e-04    1.6053056 0.108426561 0.0019763260 -1.965968e-04
o3median    0.0002212612 2.248015e-04    0.9842516 0.324991826 0.0006618641 -2.193416e-04\
```

---

### Edit in light of comments

If you have a number of gam models, say `ap1`, `ap2`, `ap3` and you wish to deal with them systematically, an `R`ish approach is to put them in a list and use `lapply`

```
# create list
model_list <- list(ap1, ap2, ap3)
# give the elements useful names
names(model_list) <- c('ap1','ap2','ap3')

# get the summaries using `lapply

summary_list <- lapply(model_list, summary)

# extract the coefficients from these summaries

 p.table_list <- lapply(summary_list, `[[`, 'p.table')

 s.table_list <- lapply(summary_list, `[[`, 's.table')
```

the lists you have created now the relevant components.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer, that was exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: I would like to revive this question and hope I do not break forum rules. How can I store the coefficients of several gam objects (mgcv package) in a systematic way? Presently I am storing each estimate individually and could not figure out how to do it for several objects.

Comment: Dear mnel,
Thanks, your help is greatly appreciated. The coefficients are found in the summary list which I have slightly altered as follows:

summary_list <- lapply(model_list, summary)
p.table_list <- lapply(summary_list, `[[`, 'p.table')